# How to correctly free a DragObject

Tags: delphi, memory-management, memory-leaks, drag-and-drop, drag

I got a memory leak error after drag & drop.

[image: memory leak error]

```
TMyDragObject = class(TDragObject)
public
    MyInfo : string;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  Button1.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1StartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  DragObject := TMyDragObject.Create;
  TMyDragObject(DragObject).MyInfo := 'hi!';
end;
```

Where should DragObject be freed?
Thanks to all.

Comment: Since you create it in `OnStartDrag`, wouldn't a logical place to free it be in `OnEndDrag`?

Comment: Sure, but it's never fired. Is there something missing?

Comment: Where's your code for `OnDragDrop` and `OnDragOver` for the control accepting the drag operation?

Comment: They're not relevant, memory leak also occurs without accepting drag & drop operation.

Comment: Inherit your `TMyDragObject` from `TDragObjectEx` , as such it will be automatically freed at the end of the drag operation.

Comment: Ignore my first comment (it's wrong). Your OnDragDrop code is not, however; see my answer below.

Comment: @Peter: It's the right thing to do, no more memory leaks now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Free the object in the `OnDragDrop` handler for the control accepting the drop. Here's the event for a TMemo:

```
procedure TForm4.Memo1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsDragObject(Source) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(TMyDragObject(Source).MyInfo);
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Here's a more complete (and very trivial) example. Drop a TButton and TMemo on the form, set `Button1.DragMode` to `dmAutomatic`, add the variable `Ctr: Integer` to the form's `private` section, and wire up the event handlers; it allows you to drag the button into the memo, adding the text `Item` + the current value of Ctr to the memo's lines.

```
type
  TMyDragObject=class(TDragObject)
    Info: string;
  end;

procedure TForm4.Button1StartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  Inc(Ctr);
  DragObject := TMyDragObject.Create;
  TMyDragObject(DragObject).Info := 'Item ' + IntToStr(Ctr);
end;

procedure TForm4.Memo1DragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if IsDragObject(Source) then
  begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(TMyDragObject(Source).Info);
    Source.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm4.Memo1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
  Accept := IsDragObject(Source);
end;
```

As an alternative, inherit from `TDragObjectEx`, which is automatically freed at the end of the drop operation, according to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TDragObject).

> Note: TDragObject is not automatically freed at the end of a drag
>   operation. To work with a drag object that is freed at the end of the
>   drag operation, use TDragObjectEx instead

Comment: DragObject is also created when drag and drop isn't accepted and this can cause memory leaks. Inheriting from TDragObjectEx seems to be the only solution...